# Create form for recursive model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, self-reference

Hello I am trying to create a form in which Model A has many and belong to itself. I tried using nested_form and no luck yet.
I want to create nested form for just Model A.
Can anyone suggest me correct path ?

Answer (score 0):

Without more details on your models and structure it's hard to help, maybe include some code too?

For nested models you typically do something like this:

```
<%= form_for @model_a do |model_a_form| %>
  <%= model_a_form.text_field :attribute_1 %>
  <%= model_a_form.text_field :attribute_2 %>

  <%= fields_for :child_models, @model_a.child_models do |child_models_fields| %>
    <%= child_models_fields.text_field :attribute_1 %>
    <%= child_models_fields.text_field :attribute_2 %>
  <% end %>

  <%= model_a_form.submit %>
<% end %>
```

See https://apidock.com/rails/ActionView/Helpers/FormHelper/fields_for for more info.

Comment: How do i nest further when i need to more object to child_models ?

Comment: Did the above work for just one of your nested objects? Try first with that base case above, if it works for you then you can seperate those fields out into partials and call them for each model.